Within the constraints of modern technology what is the most accurate design for how a walking city could work?
Can massive moving structures that are home to cities be built within the constraints of physics and modern technology? Fuel constraints are not a concern.
Context: In my world building project, the last of humanity lives on a very large island. The tides and ocean environment are now much more extreme and the tides reach deep into the island when they come. I haven't decided how often yet, but very often massive floods drown most of the island. The island is divided by a giant mountain range which is almost impossible to climb. One faction of the humans that was too violent and war like was banished to the other side of the mountains, where the land is much flatter and more prone to flooding. Their solution was to build cities that could move to a safer location sadly though nowhere beyond the mountains is safe for long so they have to keep moving. due to the amount of resources needed to construct those cities, the land has been stripped of all valuable materials making those people even more hungry for conquest. If it is even possible, how would those cities have to be designed, and theoretically how big could they be?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Realistic is a subjective quality based on someone's personal understanding of how the world works. As such asking for the most realistic something isn't an appropriate question for this site. Also please remember that we have a strict one question per post policy on this site.

How would you recommend I change my question?

Philip Reeve, Mortal Engines Quartet (2001-2006). Bad film adaptation by Christian Rivers (2018). "The series is set thousands of years in the future in a time known as the Traction Era, in which Earth has been reduced to a wasteland by a devastating conflict known as the Sixty Minute War. Traction Cities—mobile cities often mounted on caterpillar tracks—are fiercely independent city-states that use giant mechanical jaws to dismantle one another for resources." (Wikipedia)

Hi, I'm pretty new here and I have some questions regarding how unrealistic my world-building is. If there are things I can improve about how I use this site I would love to hear feedback.

How do you define "most accurate"? By asking for anything that a walking city could work your question has an incredibly broad range of valid answers. Try asking a much more specific question about a particular problem you are facing. The answers will likely be far more useful to you than an open ended overly broad query.

I've watched the Mortal Engines movie, I agree the book is definitely better. Theoretically how possible would it be to build the cities like the ones in that movie? I know its a silly question but it might be a good start.

Thanks for the feed back

Suggested reading: Absolution Gap by Alistair Reynolds has mobile cathedrals; Inverted World by Christopher Priest has a city that moves on rails.

Thanks so mutch! I will definitely check those out

Something you may wish to consider: what do they eat? Even in today's extremely urbanized life, built-up areas only account for a few percent of developed land, almost all of it is farms.

Hello Oog, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. For future reference and to avoid question closure: (a) You're allowed to ask one and only one question. You're asking two questions (design vs. size). (b) You're asking a very large and ambiguous question. It's not within the scope of this site to design your entire city. You should focus on something that can be answered with a single page of text. (c) The [tag:hard-science] tag is ruthless (please read the wiki!). Because of it, the only valid answer is, "it can't be done." I suggest replacing it with [tag:science-fiction].

What you're describing isn't actually a walking city, it's an extremely large all-terrain capable RV. Such a thing isn't technically impossible, it's just not possible with what most people consider reasonable limitations.
The first obstacle you'll run into is the suspension. If you're thinking "walking" then you're already in the wrong ballpark. Walking involves conveying a significant portion of the vehicle's weight on a small portion of its surface area. You want to go the other direction, spreading your weight out across more surface area. Not only are feet a bad idea, even wheels fail to effectively manage this issue. Most people think in terms of tracked vehicles when getting this big, which is why Mortal Engines turned out the way it did, but that doesn't scale up, either.
The second issue you'll run into is variable terrain. That's why most people think in terms of walking. You want each point under your city to have effectively independent suspension so it can average out the height.
Unfortunately, independent suspension is anathema to spreading the weight out evenly. The ultimate form of this is ground effects; essentially lifting everything on a cushion of air. The obstacle you run into then is figuring out how to make a skirt that keeps enough air in to keep the whole thing lifted, and generating enough pressure under the city to keep it off the ground.
If you can conquer those two, then the next obstacle would be traction. How do you keep a gigaton vehicle from sliding downhill? At this point, you probably want to shift to segmenting your city. So, for instance, each building might have its own chainmail balloon under it. They're all connected together in ways that they can pull each other uphill. The ones on the edge would need to be specially designed to climb hills on their own, then anchor, then draw the next building up.
The whole thing wouldn't be very fast. It'll ripple across the surface like a millipede. You aren't going to chase anybody with your city. The ground-effects might allow the thing to float, and that's a better way to avoid flooding in any case.

Don't Walk. Float:
The simplest solution is to only build real cities on high ground. You can certainly have large flood walls, but these locations will hold heavy industry and the like. That doesn't solve the problem of exploiting all that land that becomes available at lower tides.
The obvious, minimal tech/least engineering solution isn't to try and design a city that walks at all. The mechanics are resource-intensive, hard to make and hard to maintain. There would likely be thick layers of silt that could cause a heavy walking device to become hopelessly mired, then drowned out. But since your problem is flooding, build your city on a series of barges.
Your "city" can be anchored in place on dry land, built locally, and the materials for relatively simple barges are fairly robust and diverse, including steel, wood and even concrete. Large concrete pylons provide secure points that can be bridged by large cables. When flooding comes, your city floats up until the water subsides. If the water stays up, the barges with motors can sail to the next promising destination. Those without can be towed or use hoists to pull themselves between pylons across the water.
When the tides subside, your mobile cities sail back out with the tides and anchor where they want the new city to be. The water goes down and your city is sitting on dry land. If buildings need to shift around a bit, they are functionally huge sleds that can use hoists and concrete pylons to push and pull to the exact desired spot.

Your city can thus be easily relocated to higher or lower ground.
Of course, this assumes you actually want your cities ON the land. It might be easier to build piers, floating docks and pylons, then anchor you city just offshore (wherever "just off shore" happens to be). The city never goes on dry land. You perpetually have a port city with access to water transportation.
